# How to format all dates in a sheet by Pandas？

Tags: python, pandas

I had the below sheet data in a excel file:

```
id   data_1                 data_2
1    2018/11/11 00:00       123
2    123                    2018/11/2 00:00
```

The date in excel actully is a float, so I want change it to str by using the following syntax:

```
df = df.astype(dtype=str)
```

But the pandas change the date format `YYYY/MM/DD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`,so I get this in the output:

```
id   data_1                 data_2
1    2018-11-11 00:00       123
2    123                    2018-11-2 00:00
```

How do change all dates to str and keep it format as `YYYY/MM/DD`?

I'm unable to use `df.to_datetime()` or some syntax like this, because not all dates are in a particular column.And I don't want to traverse all columns to achieve it.

The only way I konw is use regex:

```
df.replace(['((?<=[0-9]{4})-(?=([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})))|((?<=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})-(?=[0-9]{2}))'], ['/'], regex=True)
```

But it will lead to errors while I have a `YYYY-MM-DD` data in some other str data.

I only want change the date type in sheet, and `df.astype` can do it. The only problem is I want `YYYY/MM/DD` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

In general, I want change all dates in sheet to type of str. And format it to `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`. `astype` can achieve the first step.

Is there a simple and quick way to achieve this?

Think you for reading.

Comment: `The date in excel actully is a float`. But you haven't given us floats to work with. Can you show us *precisely* the `float` data you see in Excel?

Comment: Also, you can use `dtype ` parameter in `pd.read_excel` to specify the `dtype` of the column you want to read it as in pandas

Comment: @jpp Its like `43405.0` and its a timestamp. `df.astype(dtype=str)` can identify it and format it to str like `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: @Vivek Kalyanarangan Actually, Its same as `df.astype(dtype=str)`.It will format the date to str like `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: @LING173 in that case try looking at [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert to desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider you have a dataframe with datetime objects but also random integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2018,1,1), dt.datetime(2018,1,6)))
df[0][0] = 123
print(df)
    0
0   123
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-01-03
3   2018-01-04
4   2018-01-05
5   2018-01-06
```

now you can create a new column with the datetime in the desired format by using `df.apply` and this function `convert`:

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    except AttributeError:
        return str(x)

df['date'] = df[0].apply(convert)
print(df)

                     0        date
0                  123         123
1  2018-01-02 00:00:00  2018/01/02
2  2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018/01/03
3  2018-01-04 00:00:00  2018/01/04
4  2018-01-05 00:00:00  2018/01/05
5  2018-01-06 00:00:00  2018/01/06
```

Note: it might be a better idea to clean up the dates first to avoid unexpected behavior. For example with this

```
df[df[0].apply(lambda x: type(x)==pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)]
```

Comment: Thank you .The problem is `df[0]` contain other data, maybe a `str`, maybe a `float`. Actully I have no idea which column contain a date and I don't want search each column.